# Subtracting an entire column by a value

Tags: r

I am new to R and need a little help. I have a data set with 13 columns. One column has height measurements and is appropriately titled "Height". I want to subtract 2 from each value in that column. What function would I use to do so?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. You can probably just do `mydata$Height <- mydata$Height-2`

Comment: yourdata$Height <- yourdata$Height - 2

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments,

```
yourdata$Height <- yourdata$Height - 2
```

will work to subtract two from the dataset "yourdata" and the column "Height", and then it replaces "<-" that column "yourdata$Height".

If you want to keep the original column as is, and add a new column, then you need to change the name of your new 'object'. Such as:

```
yourdata$HeightMinus2 <- yourdata$Height - 2
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to comments which work, a "tidy" way to do this is:

```
library(dplyr)
new_df <- initial_df %>% mutate(Height = Height - 2)
```

Comment: Best to just load `dplyr` for this one task.